# How to check if IShellFolder is a drive?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, com, windows-shell

I'm trying to filter folders displayed in SHBrowseForFolder and limit it to drives. I'm filtering this through IFilterFolder interface which lets me access the folder being displayed using IShellFolder interface.

Is there a way to check if a given IShellFolder is a drive ?

Comment: `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf(SHGDN_FORPARSING)` and see if the result is a drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

GetAttributesOf() member function of IShellFolder can be used to get attributes which will be zero for top level drive items in the list. I could not find any other alternative to this currently.

Comment: Um, top-level drive items will still report SFGAO_FOLDER, SFGAO_CANLINK and several other attributes. Not sure why you claim they will report 0.

Comment: Not sure why this happens either :( (could be an error in the way I'm using GetAttributesOf() function). Here is the listing of my filter function: http://pastebin.com/kGH3aVJ7

Comment: Um, the last parameter of GetAtributesOf is an INOUT parameter that says what flags you are interested in. You said you are interested in no flags, so the results are garbage.

Comment: Aah, you are correct. The attributes became non-zero after passing proper flags. I'm able to filter for drives using GetDisplayNameOf(). Thanks for all the help Raymond :)